# Fetch and display Google Doc body within html page

Tags: content-management-system, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

Is it possible to retrieve the content of a Google Doc and display it within a div in an html page? If so, what's the right way to implement the "MAGIC" in the stripped-down example below?

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div>
          <MAGIC>
            Script or link that retrieves and displays the body of a Google Doc.
          </MAGIC>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above, you can assume

1. The html is served by Google Drive Hosting.
2. The reference to the Google Doc is static.
3. There is no need to edit the Doc from within the public html page (i.e it's read-only in that context).

I've read through the Apps Script documentation and it looks as though something might be possible with some combination of Document Service and Content Service. For instance, Document Service has getBody() and copy() methods, but it's not clear whether the objects returned by these calls can be rendered WYSIWYG as html for insertion into an html container.

**Background:** I'm trying to implement a safe easy-to-use CMS for a small nonprofit. I've prototyped a website framework that's hosted
on Google Drive. So far it looks promising,  but changes require being able to edit the html.   We have a number of people who can create content in a word-processor-like environment but only couple including myself
who can cope with HTML/CSS/JQuery/AppsScript.

If I could concentrate on the overall framework and let the others update the content for 
events, etc., that would be a huge win. Basically, I'd be very happy if they were able to edit the Google Doc and then manually reload the web page to see the result.

I realize there are many approaches for CMS, but for now, I'm interested in exploring a pure Google Docs/Google Drive solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've settled on publishing the content docs and including the iframe embed code supplied by Google to implement the "MAGIC" from my original question, e.g

```html
<iframe class="cmsframe" src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rhkuAB3IIu5Hq0tEtA4E_Qy_-sJMMnb33WBMlAEqlJU/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>
```

The class tag is added manually so I can control the iframe size with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the raw html content of a google doc with a call to the drive API using urlFetch, here is how it works

```js
      var id = 'Doc-Very-Long-ID-Here';
      var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
      var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/documents/Export?exportFormat=html&format=html&id='+id,
                                  googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getContentText();

   // the variable doc is the HTML content that you can use

    function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
      var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
      oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
      oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
      oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
      oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
      oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
      return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
    }
```

There is also a library by Romain Vialard [available here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/driveservice) it is called DocsListExtended and provides a whole bunch of nice extensions.

---

**EDIT :** *Following your EDIT:*

You **can't** use it just like that, to render an HTML content in a webapp use [html service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service?hl=fr-FR), example below with your complete code  and [working example](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx2_NCOXftcwHchtIDMgT_tAp0mFLCcYPaEIahavFT679K9EJtG/exec):

```js
function doGet() {

    var id = '1el3DpTp1sukDjzlKXh8plf0Zj-qm0drI7KbytroVrNU';
    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
    var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/documents/Export?exportFormat=html&format=html&id='+id, googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getContentText();
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(doc);
}

// the variable doc is the HTML content that you can use

function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
    var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
    oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
    oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
    oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
    return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Serge.  It looks sensible, but I'm having trouble making it work.  See above where I've edited my post with your solution as I've implemented it in App Script. I'm getting a 404. Have included doc id so you can verify it.  It's just a doc containing the sentence "This is a test of the CMS system."

Comment: Fixed id string to include just the id.  No more 404 but now getting "The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type."

Comment: Thanks for this. I've verified that it works in a webapp context.  Unfortunately, I've run into a "same origin" problem because my web pages are hosted by googledrive.com but the content pages live in docs.google.com.  Otherwise, your answer is a good one and I appreciate the time you took to educate me on HtmlService, oAuth, and UrlFetchApp.